# Eloquent ORM - retorno de dados de subtabela?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, orm

Sou iniciante em Laravel e me deparei com a seguinte situação. Possuo uma tabela Certidao que possui uma chave estrangeira para a Tabela Vara que possui uma chave estrangeira para a tabela Comarca. Como faço para retornar dados que estão na tabela Comarca utilizando Eloquent ORM?

Meu certidaoController.php onde faço a requisição dos dados

```
public function owner()
{
    return Certidao::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->orderby('numero_cpha')
        ->with(['advogado', 'assunto', 'banco', 
         'comarca', 'juiz', 'materia', 'sistema', 
         'vara', 'ato', 'parte'])
        ->get();
}
```

Meus modelo `certidao.php`

```
* Comarca de Origem
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasOne
 */
public function comarca()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Comarca::class);
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Vara de Origem
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\hasOne
 */
public function vara()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Vara::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Possuo uma tabela Certidao que possui uma chave estrangeira para a Tabela Vara que possui uma chave estrangeira para a tabela Comarca

Basicamente `Certidao -> Vara -> Comarca` no momento de chamar as relações utilize sempre `with` (carregamento adiantado e otimizado) colocando na relação da seguinte forma:

```
Certidao::with(['vara.comarca'])->get();
```

Ou seja, quando existe uma relação e relação subsequentes e assim por diante monte a seguinte lógica: separada por um ponto (`.`) como demonstrada `'vara.comarca'`.

Na documentação isso e chamado de [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading), em tradução

> Para carregar antecipadamente os relacionamentos de um relacionamento,
> você pode usar a sintaxe "ponto". Por exemplo, vamos carregar todos os
> autores do livro e todos os contatos pessoais do autor:

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

Use sempre essa forma de carregar relação, ela é otimizada e não executa mais `SQL` do que precisa, quando é utilizado o carregamento preguiçoso traz um desempenho ruim, por chamar em todas as interações uma consulta `SQL`.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#introduction)
- [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)

Comment: Então o código do meu Controller ficaria assim? ` public function owner()
{
    return Certidao::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->orderby('numero_cpha')
        ->with(['advogado', 'assunto', 'banco', 
         'juiz', 'materia', 'sistema', 
         'vara.comarca', 'ato', 'parte'])
        ->get();
} `

Comment: Não! você não fez o que eu falei: `public function owner() {  return Certidao::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderby('numero_cpha')->with(['advogado', 'assunto', 'banco','vara.comarca', 'juiz', 'materia', 'sistema', 'ato', 'parte'])->get(); }` acho que isso funciona, não tenho como testar, mas, lógica é essa! @amd-ads uma dica infalivel leia a documentação

Comment: Então a sua pergunta pergunta sobre próxima relação, se está dando erro 500 precisa entrar na pergunta colocar os models, exemplificar relamente o que está fazendo e colocar também a mensagem de erro @adm-ads

Comment: Deu certo! Precisava inserir a busca da Comarca no model da Vara. Os dados vieram.  Muito Obrigada!!!

Comment: Perseguição !!! votos negativos ...!